# How to prevent Liferay from doing 301 redirect?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have cloned my Liferay machine and got another instance with different IP and DNS. Unfortunately, once I visit my new address, server does 301 redirect to old address.

I can visit new site, can't open it's control panel etc, since it's always throws me to old name.

How to overcome?

**UPDATE**

I have edited my `hosts` file so that it points `myoldname.mydomain.com` to new IP. This way I am able to browse new site under old name.

I went to `Portal Settings` and changed `Virtual Host` parameter from "localhost" to `mynewname.mydomain.com`

I was thinking that this parameter controls redirect but was wrong: it still occurs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The virtual host setting can also be done *per site* - check if your site has a virtual host configured as well (it's in the site's settings/configuration, should be easy to find)